# Show that $\exists \eta \in (a,b) ~s.t.~\frac{f(\eta)}{\int_a^{\eta} f(t){\rm d}t}-\frac{g(\eta)}{\int_{\eta}^b g(t){\rm d}t}=2021$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Suppose $f(x),g(x) \in C[a,b]$ and $f(x),g(x)>0$ for every $x \in (a,b)$. Show that there exists a $\eta \in (a,b)$ such that $$\frac{f(\eta)}{\int_a^{\eta} f(t){\rm d}t}-\frac{g(\eta)}{\int_{\eta}^b g(t){\rm d}t}=2021.$$

This problem comes from [here](https://www.zhihu.com/question/435703720), a website of China.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT.** We can generalize $2021$ to arbitrary $k$. Let
$$
F(x)=\int_{a}^{x} f(t)\mathrm{d}t ,G(x)=\int_{x}^{b} g(t)\mathrm{d}t
$$
And the original claim is equivalent to
$$
\frac{F'\left( \eta \right)}{F\left( \eta \right)}+\frac{G'\left( \eta \right)}{G\left( \eta \right)}=k
$$
Then
$$
F'\left( \eta \right) G\left( \eta \right) +G'\left( \eta \right) F\left( \eta \right) =kF\left( \eta \right) G\left( \eta \right) \\
F'\left( \eta \right) G\left( \eta \right) +G'\left( \eta \right) F\left( \eta \right) -kF\left( \eta \right) G\left( \eta \right) =0
$$
Let
$$
H (x)=C e^{-kx}F(x )G(x )
$$
What can we say about $H(x)$?

> $$
> H'(x)=C (F'\left( \eta \right) G\left( \eta \right) +G'\left( \eta \right) F\left( \eta \right) -kF\left( \eta \right) G\left( \eta \right) )
> $$
> Since $H(a)=H(b)=0$, we can apply *Rolle's Theorem*.

Comment: $$
H (x)=C e^{-kx}F(x )G(x )
$$

Comment: Yeah, thanks for pointing out that

Comment: I don't get the sign change in the second formula. I had done
$$
\frac{F'\left( \eta \right)}{F\left( \eta \right)}-\frac{G'\left( \eta \right)}{G\left( \eta \right)}=k
$$

Comment: Notice that $G(x)=\int_{x}^{b} g(t)\mathrm{d}t$ so that $G'(x)=-g(x)$

Comment: I did the equation again $y'-k y=0$ and got $y=Ce^{k x}$ without the minus sign

Comment: What do you solve that for?

Comment: for $x$ it's $\frac{dy}{ky}=dx\to y=Ce^{kx}$

Comment: Please take a look of the things I added just now

Comment: @FFjet: See https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16373/42969 about voting to close a question *and* also answering it. *“If you vote to close, you are saying that the question should not be answered. – If you also answer it, you contradict yourself.”*

Comment: @MartinR I see. I will pay attention at next time. Thanks for mentioning me that.

Comment: Btw, I don't see why it should be necessary to add the factor $C$. $H (x)=e^{-kx}F(x )G(x )$ as in the original version of your answer just works fine.

Comment: Yeah, $C$ is not necessary. Well, according to the comments, I think adding $C$ can represent a more general class of functions. This doesn’t influence the correctness tho :D